# How can I compute the frequencies of itemsets using R?

Tags: r

My input file contains a transaction on each line. The following example shows the structure of my input file:

```
a
a
a,b
b
a,b
a,c
c
c
```

The above input file has 11 items and 8 itemsets. This input file has 3 unique items and 5 unique itemsets. I would like to compute the frequencies of each unique itemset. For the above input file, I'd like to write an R script that generates an output similar to the following CSV file:

```
"a",0.25
"a,b",0.25
"c",0.25
"b",0.125
"a,c",0.125
```

The report presents the number of occurrences of each unique itemset in the input transactions file divided by the total number of item sets in the input. Note that the report has sorted the itemsets based on their frequencies. How can I use R to compute the frequencies of the itemsets in my input transactions file?

**UPDATE:** I've already computed the association rules using the [read.transactions](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/read.transactions.html) and [apriori](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arules/html/apriori.html) methods. Can I reuse the results of these methods to compute the frequencies of the input itemsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
Data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
itemset
a
a
a,b
b
a,b
a,c
c
c")

cbind(table(Data), table(Data) / nrow(Data))

## EDIT: Include sorting by observed proportion
T <- table(Data)                        # observed freq.
T <- cbind(T, T/nrow(Data))             # combine freq. and prop.
T <- T[order(T[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]  # sort
colnames(T) <- c("freq", "prop")        # add column names
```

Comment: @reprogrammer I apologize. Updated.

Comment: Can anyone help me, why I get the error when i try to execute the first line of code?

Error in read.table(header = TRUE, text = "\nitemset\na\na\na,b\nb\na,b\na,c\nc\nc") : 
  unused argument(s) (text = "\nitemset\na\na\na,b\nb\na,b\na,c\nc\nc")

Comment: @moldovean Are you attempting to enter the data in a single line?

Comment: @JasonMorgan Well.. I just copy/pasted, I thought it would work. But it gives me an error. 
: unused argument(s) (text = " \nitemset \na \na \na, b\nb \na, b\na, c\nc")

Comment: @moldovean What I mean is did you enter the data in multiple lines, as in the example, or a single line, as in you copy-paste to the above comments? Try entering the data by hand, exactly as it is above.

Comment: nope... it doesn't work.. those \n mean actually a new line
but it works if i put that on a different file

Answer (score 7):

```
dat <- read.table(text="a
a
a,b
b
a,b
a,c
c
c")
prop.table(table(dat$V1))

#    a   a,b   a,c     b     c 
#0.250 0.250 0.125 0.125 0.250 
 dat.prop <- as.data.frame( prop.table(table(dat$V1)) )
 dat.prop <- dat.prop[order(dat.prop$Freq, decreasing=TRUE), ]
 dat.prop
#-------- Added the order step as a revision
  Var1  Freq
1    a 0.250
2  a,b 0.250
5    c 0.250
3  a,c 0.125
4    b 0.125
#---------

 write.table(dat.prop, file="dat.prop.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: I think this method is the simplest and most straight forward.

Comment: There is no need for prop.table(). table() works fine. See my answer below.

Comment: Well, you either need to divide by the `NROW` of the dataframe or use `prop.table`. I chose to offer `prop.table` because it generalizes to higher dimensions

Comment: True. While it doesn't matter for this small problem, `prop.table` is pretty inefficient: it calculates `x/sum(x)` when `nrow` is already available from the `data.frame` object.

Comment: Have you looked at the code? It is basically x/sum(x), so we are really arguing over nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If the input data is in a file called 'dat.txt', then this code would work. The output would be in a file in the same directory called 'out.csv'.

```
Y=read.table('dat.txt')
Y=as.character(unlist(Y))
U=unique(Y)
n=length(U)
F=rep(0,n)
for(i in 1:n) F[i] = mean(Y==U[i])
D=cbind(U,F)
colnames(D)=c("Value","Frequency")
write.csv(D,'out.csv')
```

My apologies that this code is neither pretty nor commented.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "V1", summarize, Freq = length(V1)/NROW(dat))

   V1  Freq
1   a 0.250
2 a,b 0.250
3 a,c 0.125
4   b 0.125
5   c 0.250
```

Comment: easy to fix by sorting on frequencies.

Comment: Would you please update your code to sort by frequencies descendingly?