# How to compute the frequency of the transition between the two states?

Tags: r, frequency

My dataset looks like this:

```
Data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
itemset
aac,
cca,
bab,
caa,
aba,
abb,
cab,
bcc,
aca,
bab,
cca,
cac,
baa,
baa,
abc,
abb,
cbb,
baa,
cba,
acb,
ccb,
bbc,
aac,
bac,
abb,
bba,
bca,
acc,
caa,
cca")
```

Let's say that each line corresponds one state. I need to compute the frequency of the transition between the two neighboring states.

**Question.** Is exist the standard functions?

I have found the partical answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768560/how-can-i-compute-the-frequencies-of-itemsets-using-r)

```
cbind(table(Data), table(Data) / nrow(Data))

Tab <- table(Data)                        # observed freq.
Tab <- cbind(Tab, Tab/nrow(Data))             # combine freq. and prop.
Tab <- Tab[order(Tab[,2], decreasing=TRUE),]  # sort
colnames(Tab) <- c("freq", "prop")        # add column names
```

The `dim(Tab)[1]` is 22, and the result should be the `22x22` matrix.

Comment: `1.` don't name any object `T`. (its reserved for TRUE), `2.`. What does your 22x22 Matrix look like. (**show your desired outcome!**)

Comment: It seems that you are looking for `table`: `table(Data$itemset[-1], Data$itemset[-nrow(Data)])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way with `reshape2`, yielding a 21x21 probability transition matrix

```
library(reshape2)
Data <- data.frame(Data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Data$nextitem <- c(as.character(Data$itemset[-1]), NA)
Data$value <- 1
df <- dcast(Data, itemset~nextitem, fill=0)
df <- df[-ncol(df)]
df[-1] <- df[-1] / rowSums(df[-1]) # assuming no rows have all zeros
df
#   itemset aac aba abb       abc aca acb acc       baa bab bac       bba bbc bca bcc caa       cab cac       cba       cbb cca ccb
#1      aac   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.5 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5   0
#2      aba   0 0.0   1 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#3      abb   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.3333333   0   0   0 0.0 0.3333333 0.0 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.0   0
#4      abc   0 0.0   1 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#5      aca   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 1.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#6      acb   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   1
#7      acc   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 1.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#8      baa   0 0.0   0 0.3333333   0   0   0 0.3333333 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0   0
#9      bab   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.5 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5   0
#10     bac   0 0.0   1 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#11     bba   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   1   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#12     bbc   1 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#13     bca   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   1 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#14     bcc   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   1   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#15     caa   0 0.5   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5   0
#16     cab   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   1 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#17     cac   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 1.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#18     cba   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   1   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#19     cbb   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 1.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#20     cca   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.5 0.0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
#21     ccb   0 0.0   0 0.0000000   0   0   0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0 0.0000000   1   0   0 0.0 0.0000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0   0
```

Comment: I have run the code on test 'Data' and all values in df['cca',] are NA's.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame( Data, stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) %>%
  #remove the comma
  mutate( itemset = gsub( ",", "", itemset) ) %>%
  #create colum with next state
  mutate( next_itemset = lead( itemset, n = 1 ) )

xtabs(  ~ itemset + next_itemset, df) / nrow(df)
```

Comment: yes you are right. Only 1's should be devided on the size of table.

Comment: @Nick divide the xtab by `nrow(df)`, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This code creates the 22x22 matrix you are after.

```
Data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
itemset
aac,
cca,
bab,
caa,
aba,
abb,
cab,
bcc,
aca,
bab,
cca,
cac,
baa,
baa,
abc,
abb,
cbb,
baa,
cba,
acb,
ccb,
bbc,
aac,
bac,
abb,
bba,
bca,
acc,
caa,
cca")




Data$second_state <- c(as.character(Data$itemset[-1]),NA)


Data %>% 
  group_by(itemset,second_state) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(second_state) & !is.na(itemset)) %>% 
  count() %>% spread(second_state,n)
```